# Is there any merit to only asking for part of a user's password?

Tags: authentication, passwords, banks

The HSBC UK online banking website has a strangely convoluted login system that I haven't seen anywhere else before, and which I'm concerned is ineffectual and compromises security. It works like this:

1. I enter my username, then forwarded to a new page for the next steps.
2. I am asked a "memorable question", and enter my "memorable answer" in full.
3. I am asked for three characters from specific positions in my password. As far as I can tell, they are *always* the same three positions.

I am used to Australian banks just asking me for my username and password, potentially with an SMS authentication step.

Here's a screenshot of the page in which steps 2 and 3 are carried out:

> [image: "answer your memorable question; enter the 1st, 2nd and 5th characters of your password."]

**Is there any advantage at all to doing this, or is this poor security compared to just asking for my password in full?** I am concerned that not only is this needlessly complex, it is actually *worse* security than just asking for my password outright, because a potentially quite long and complex password is effectively reduced to a 3-character password.

As far as I'm concerned right now, my "memorable answer" has taken on the traditional password role, and my "password" is just an extra three characters I have for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, it's dumb. Super dumb. I think banks only hire web devs who fail security exams.

Comment: Oh too bad. I was going to switch to HSBC but now I'm reconsidering my choice..

Comment: Thanks for the dupe suggestion, @Mike. Glad it's not just me thinking badly of it.

Comment: @Andre I'm reconsidering my choice of HSBC too. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° )